# Crack the expression

Tags: mysql, expression, qlikview, qliksense

I am trying to understand expression in QV for the past few days and am unable to follow what it is trying to do especially the aggregate part with a nodistinct sum.

I've tried to understand how aggregate works and how nodistinct with sum but am not able to connect with the rest of the expression.

```
sum([INFLUENCE ON SALE]
* aggr(NODISTINCT  SUM({<PART_NUMBER, [INFLUENCE ON SALE],[Campaign 
Name],ROOTCAUSE=>}[TOTAL OCCATIONS 12]),KEY,YEAR)
/aggr(NODISTINCT  SUM({<PART_NUMBER, [INFLUENCE ON SALE],[Campaign 
Name],ROOTCAUSE=>}[TOTAL OCCATIONS 12]),YEAR))
```

WHAT is this expression trying to do with the aggregate and nodistinct part. can this be simplified and explained with a simple example?

Comment: sum([INFLUENCE ON SALE] * aggr(NODISTINCT SUM({<PART_NUMBER,[INFLUENCE ON Sale],[Campaign Name],Rootcause=>}[TOTAL OCCATIONS 12]),KEY,YEAR) /aggr(NODISTINCT SUM({<PART_NUMBER,[INFLUENCE ON Sale],[Campaign Name],Rootcause=>}[TOTAL OCCATIONS 12]),YEAR))

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question with meaningless code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to show the chart (table) in order to understand the use of `nodistinct` in this specific calculation. `nodistinct` "spreads" the results across dimensions even though the dimension is not in the `aggr` function...